# Should i always unregister a local broadcast receiver

Tags: android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have an Android app that uses local broadcasts to pass information from an activity to a custom preference (that extends the `Preference` class). I register the receiver in the `OnCreateView` method of the preference:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance (Context).RegisterReceiver(...);
```

I have read that broadcast receivers must be unregistered in the `OnPause` / `OnStop` methods in an activity, but the preference doesn't have these methods.

Should i always unregister a broadcast receiver? What happens if i don't? Can (Should) broadcast receivers be used in other classes besides activities?

Comment: It might lead to memory leak , if you don't unregister

Answer (score 0):

you can unregister in when go back

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```